# Variable {...} cuelga la app

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

En ocasiones me sucede que tengo un error que yo supongo esta sin `Try-Catch` ya que me cierra de golpe la app.

Entonces reviso el codigo paso a paso y me encuentro con listas o variables que en lugar de decir:

```
-null
-""
-"algo"
```

Me muestra algo asi:

```
-{...}
```

Y al pasar sobre esta linea me cuelga la app hasta que la detengo a la fuerza.

A alguien mas le sucede?

He tenido que hacer cosas que en teoría considero que no debería tener que hacer como:

```
if (Lista.Count < 1)
{
   // Vacio
   Lista.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Podría deberse a que es una clase con muchísimas propiedades o elementos y por eso se queda "congelada" hasta que puede mostrar todo su contenido en el depurador. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo en el que podamos ver el comportamiento para poder explicarte mejor el motivo?

Comment: Claro, en cuanto tengo una captura la comparto.  Estuve intentando tomar una captura para adjuntar pero me paso como cuando vas al doctor (al momento de querer mostrar el problema, el problema no se muestra).

Comment: También podría ser una referencia cíclica (el hijo o un descendiente de una instancia hace referencia a la instancia padre), aunque imagino que los depuradores deberían ser lo suficientemente inteligentes para darse cuenta.

Comment: no se entiende el problema. coloca un try catch y fijate la excepcion si es que te la tira, sino en la Salida del depurador.